# pi zero w does not respond

Tags: pi-zero-w

Ordered a Pi Zero w, arrived, but I did not check it before I soldered the 40 pin GPIO onto it. Now it does not seem to be starting at all.

I visually inspected the solders, they are not touching each other, then I checked for short circuit with multimeter, does not seem to have any short circuits.

Then I tried plugging everything I plugged into a working Pi 3B onto it (including the SD card, power, touch screen with HDMI and GPIO connection), no respond at all. no lights.

Then I tried to only plug in the power and SD card, no respond at all, no lights.

Is there anything else I can do to check the board? Could the soldering process have destroyed it with heat (I am not that good with solder)?

I don't want to return to seller, as it crossed continents to arrive in Asia, its not cost efficient to return.

Comment: I would say you should put noobs onto the SD from scratch, don't use one that was built for a Pi3. Have you tried this already?

Comment: Did you by any chance plug the power into the wrong USB? the one for power should be the one near the camera connector.

Comment: @hcheung you mean the one away from the Mini HDMI plug? that was the one I used.

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon I tried a clean Jessie Lite version, but not even the LED is blinking when plugged into power.

Comment: The power port is the one closest to the corner

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon yeah thats the one I used, I confirmed with some youtube video.

Comment: I had a similar issue a few weeks ago. I left the Pi's alone for a while and came back and they were working. I don't think it was soldering to be honest, I soldered headers on a Pi 0 and I did no damage to it. I hope you come right

Comment: yeah, perhaps its discharge, will try again tomorrow

Comment: no, that pi zero w is dead.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic check is to leave out any mSD card, and then to power up your Pi Zero W. It doesn't matter if your power through the power-only micro USB socket or backpower through the OTG/slave USB micro socket: both will be fine for such tests. If on power on you don't see the green ACT LED lighting up and shortly blinking, your Pi Zero W is pretty much dead.

Check your soldering for any unwanted solder bridges or solder blobs that went to places where they should not be.

As every Pi gets fully factory tested, there is a very low chance that your Pi arrived dead. There have been few cases of wrongly programmed OTP fuses, but that's not the case here.

Please note that with the Pi Zero W the meaning of the ACT LED has been reversed from it's meaning on the 3B: this allows the single ACT LED to also, erm, act as a PWR LED. So normally it should be lit. Only when there are mSD card read/write, ACT starts to blink or going dark if there are extensive read/writes; but usually only for two or three seconds at most.

Comment: "*If on power on you don't see the green ACT LED lighting up and shortly blinking, your Pi Zero W is pretty much dead*"  - Are you sure about this? That is how my rpi0w behaves, but if i plug to Windows usb port it is detected.

Answer (score 1):

[This reference](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-zero-creation/is-my-pi-zero-dead) is subtly different from @TheDiveO's answer:

- Take your Zero, with nothing in any slot or socket (yes, no SD-card
  is needed or wanted to do this test!).
- Take a normal micro-USB to USB-A DATA SYNC cable (not a
  charge-only cable! make sure its a true data sync cable!)
- Connect the USB cable to your PC, plugging the micro-USB into the
  Pi's USB, (not the PWR_IN).
- If the Zero is alive, your Windows PC will go ding for the
  presence of new hardware & you should see "BCM2708 Boot" in Device
  Manager.
- Or on linux, run `sudo lsusb` or run `dmesg` and look for a ID 0a5c:2763 
  Broadcom Corp message. If you see that,so far so good, you know the 
  Zero's not dead.

Comment: thanks for this reference Peter, anyways has left the company and the project should be long dead by now, not even sure where that zero-w board is now XD

Answer (score 0):

Without a functional SD card my pi zero W acts dead. I found this out after soldering a set of header pins ,for testing sensors,and my pi zero W was suddenly and inexplicably dead...(I solder alot) micro-scoping and removing the header pins revealed nothing abnormal; no bridged connections missing components solder-balls or extra flux buildup. testing power delivery also showed normal function.

I did noticed that it shows up as a device when plugged it to usb. (following the advice above)

So its got power, it talks to USB, and nothing seams to be physically wrong... I decided to burn a new SD card and tried that... everything instantly returned to normal.  the old SD card died when I originally removed power to add pins, I think.